# function to profile / performance test PHP functions?

Tags: php

I'm not experiencing any performance issues, however I'd like to take a look at what takes how long and how much memory cpu it uses etc.

I'd like to get a firsthand understanding of which things can be bottle necks etc and improve any code i might reuse or build upon... (perfectionist)

I'm looking to **create a little function** that i can call at the begining and end of each function that records:

- execution time
- memory used
- cpu demand

any ideas?

i haven't used things like memory_get_usage(), or methods of recording time() before so would love to get some tips on their combined implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already a host of solutions made just for that, you might want to have a look at some of these:

**[XDEBUG EXTENSION FOR PHP](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)**

> Xdebug's Profiler is a powerful tool
>   that gives you the ability to analyze
>   your PHP code and determine
>   bottlenecks or generally see which
>   parts of your code are slow and could
>   use a speed boost.

**Other Resource:**

**[PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/)**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it a lot, but friend of mine recomended http://xdebug.org/ for profiling PHP

Comment: this looks far more powerful/coples than what i need, i was looking for a simple homemade function using some of php's built in functions like memory_get_usage() - will update question

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XDebug](http://xdebug.org) to debug your code flow. XDebug will generate some file that tell how well your codes, you can use Kcachegrind to visualize that files.